# combine the result of the query in sql

Tags: sql

I am working with SQL Language. I want to combine the result of the query.
Here is my code and expected output.

```
 create table customer(name varchar,dpt varchar);

insert into customer (name,dpt)VALUES ('albe','cse');
insert into customer (name,dpt)VALUES ('bine','cse');
insert into customer (name,dpt)VALUES ('alfred','ece');
insert into customer (name,dpt)VALUES ('booshan','ece');
insert into customer (name,dpt)VALUES ('antony','eee');
insert into customer (name,dpt)VALUES ('job','ece');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
dpt,
count(name)
  from customer
  where dpt='ece' or dpt='cse'
    group by dpt;
```

**Result**:

```
| dpt | count |
|-----|-------|
| cse |   2   |
| ece |   3   |
```

I need the result as:

```
| cse/ece | 5 |
```

How it is possible?
sqlfiddle is here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a1c88/13

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are using PostgreSQL (as can be deduced from sqlfiddle link).

If this is the case, then  you can apply `array_agg` and `sum` on your query in an outer query:

```
   SELECT array_agg(dpt), sum(cnt)
   FROM (
      SELECT dpt, count(name) as cnt
      FROM customer
      WHERE dpt='ece' OR dpt='cse'
      GROUP BY dpt) t;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a1c88/24)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(dpt), SUM(cnt)
FROM(select
     dpt,
     count(name) cnt
     from customer
     where dpt='ece' or dpt='cse'
     group by dpt) t;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fde54/6)